# Get parent texInputlayout from child textInputEditText

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am implementing a functionality to change the case of `textInputlayout` Hint text to upper case **when the hint floats up and vice versa.**

For that I am using `OnFocusChangeListener` on its child `textInputEditText`. To make it easy to implement I am implementing `View.OnFocusChangeListener` on my activity like:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener
```

and overriding the method in the activity like:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(findViewById(v.getId()) instanceof TextInputEditText){
        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(v.getId()).getParent();
        if(hasFocus){
            textInputLayout.setHint(textInputLayout.getHint().toString().toUpperCase());
        }else{
            textInputLayout.setHint(Utility.modifiedLowerCase(textInputLayout.getHint().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

In the above method I am trying to get the view of parent `textInputLayout` using the line

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(v.getId()).getParent();
```

The above line of code throws a fatal error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be
>   cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

and it is very obvious because it returns `Framelayout` which cannot be casted in `textInputLayout`

And if I use

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(v.getId()).getRootView();
```

it again throws a fatal error because `getRootView()` returns `DecorView` which cannot be casted in `textInputLayout`

My question is how to get parent `textInputLayout` from child `textInputEditText`?

Please guide.

Comment: Why not assign a id to TextInputLayout in xml layout like TextInputEditText?

Comment: @DanielRL I have already assigned id in xml but it won't work here as harcoding id in my overridden method will only work for that `textinputlayout` not for others and I want it to work for my every `textinputlayout` in the layout

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved the problem with the below line of code:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(v.getId()).getParent().getParent();
```

It returns `textInputlayout` as required.

Comment: There is the opposite solution from TextInputLayout get first children(TextInputEditText)?

Comment: @peterzinho16 you can use `TextInputLayout.getEditText()`

Comment: Thanks a lot @zihadrizkyef didn't know that method

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(v.getId()).getParent();` use the instance of view like `TextInputEditText et = (TextInputEditText) v;`and then
`TextInputLayout lay = (TextInputLayout)et.getParent().getParent();`

Answer (score 0):

You can add id in TextInputLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
    style="@style/LightInputLayoutNoBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/create_contact_account_data_name"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextSmall.Bold">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/LightInputFieldNoBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_book_contacts" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And call findViewById to TextInputLayout in activity

Comment: I have already assigned id in xml but it won't work here as harcoding id in my overridden method will only work for that `textinputlayout` not for others and I want it to work for my every `textinputlayout` in the layout.

Comment: In android documentation says you can not do that: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Thus you must be asign a listener by textinputedittext and use findviewbyid.